# Mining pool rewards erc-20 smart contract

Tags: erc-20

Some time ago I invested money on the defi wallet app in the dapp ehcwa.top. It showed me a few days ago that I could claim the 15 eth reward. After I pressed the "claim" button, it showed me a smart contract from which I understood nothing. After contacting the site's support desk, I learned that I had to pay the $6742 USDT surcharge within 6 days or my money that I had in my wallet would be lost. I don't know completely what to do now. I just want my money back that was taken from me. I don't need this reward. I am very much asking for help. I am heartbroken and desperate. Please contact me back

Comment: Looks like you got scammed, unfortunately :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry to hear about the situation you're facing, but I must emphasize that it appears you may have fallen victim to a scam. The website "ehcwa.top" and the request to pay a large amount in USDT as a surcharge to claim a reward seem suspicious and not in line with standard DeFi practices. Because egitimate DeFi projects and platforms will not ask for substantial upfront payments to claim rewards.

The step you should take immediately is Stop Sending Funds. Do not send any more cryptocurrency or money to the website or the smart contract. It's crucial to halt any further transactions.

Besides, if you shared any sensitive information or private keys, take immediate steps to secure your accounts. Change passwords, enable two-factor authentication (2FA), and review the security settings of your wallets.